# Angular ng-repeat dynamic

Tags: javascript, angularjs

See this [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/G69edOB13MXKaOtsMrL8?p=preview)

In jQuery I can get the text of its **td** and put it in an alert but how can I make it in Angular? Should I make it an javascript native?

This is the script

```
var app = angular.module('plunker',[]);

app.controller('ctrl',function($scope){
  $scope.edit = function(){
    alert("ID = " + $scope.id + "\n NAME = " + $scope.name);
  };
  $scope.items = [
    {id:"1",name:"name 1"},
    {id:"2",name:"name 2"},
    {id:"3",name:"name 3"}
   ];
});
```

The HTML

```
  <body ng-controller="ctrl" ng-app="plunker">
    <table>
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>id</th>
          <th>name</th>
          <th>edit</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr ng-repeat="x in items">
          <td ng-model="x.id">{{x.id}}</td>
          <td>{{x.name}}</td>
          <td><button ng-click="edit()">edit</button></td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </body>
```

P.S

The ng-repeat is dynamic so how can I get the value of it?

Comment: Why not `edit(x.id)` or `edit(x)` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just pass the value to the edit function as parameter,

```
 <td><button ng-click="edit(x)">edit</button></td>
```

and then function would be,

```
$scope.edit = function(x){
  console.log("Id is",x.id);
}
```

**DEMO**

```js
var app = angular.module('plunker',[]);

app.controller('ctrl',function($scope){
  $scope.edit = function(){
    alert("ID = " + $scope.id + "\n NAME = " + $scope.name);
  };
  $scope.items = [
    {id:"1",name:"name 1"},
    {id:"2",name:"name 2"},
    {id:"3",name:"name 3"}
   ];
   
  $scope.edit = function(x){
   console.log("$$Id is",x.id);
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<body ng-controller="ctrl" ng-app="plunker">
    <table>
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>id</th>
          <th>name</th>
          <th>edit</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr ng-repeat="x in items">
          <td ng-model="x.id">{{x.id}}</td>
          <td>{{x.name}}</td>
          <td><button ng-click="edit(x)">edit</button></td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </body>
```

Answer (score 1):

Make your function `edit()` take a variable and then pass it in:

```
$scope.edit = function(obj){
  alert("ID = " + obj.id + "\n NAME = " + obj.name);
};
```

and then:

```
<td><button ng-click="edit(x)">edit</button></td>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create an array $scope.itemModel of size items.length in your controller and set the model in markup using $index on $scope.itemModel[$index] and then access the item by passing $index to the handler from your controller.