# AngularJS ng-repeat with unknown key value pairs

Tags: angularjs, html-table, angularjs-ng-repeat

I need to display a table using Angular ng-repeat but I don't know it's keys in advance.

Like, the response of API is `Array of Objects`

And, `each Object has unknown keys`.

[image]

In my HTML, I am doing ng-repeat over `responseData.data.rows`

```
<table id="customers">
  <tr ng-repeat = "x in myCtrl.demoDetails">

  </tr>
</table>
```

**But how would I print values in table?**

Comment: Please have a look here [Object.keys](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25299436/unable-to-call-object-keys-in-angularjs). You can make use of `Object.keys` but that has limitations with `angularjs`. Check the answer for better understanding

Answer (score 2):

It should look something like below,

```
<table class="table">
  <tr>
    <td>Task Name</td>
    <td>End Date</td>
    <td>Service Key</td>
  </tr>
<tr ng-repeat="x in responseData.data.rows">
  <td>{{x.task_name}}</td>
  <td>{{x.end_date}}</td>
  <td>{{x.service_key}}</td> 
</tr>
</table>
```

Comment: you mean `{{x.task_name}}`

Comment: @Sajeetharan precisely the issue is I don't know in advance whether it would be task_name or something else? In this case it is task_name,end_date in other cases it oculd be something else

Comment: take a look at my other answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45808072/angular-ng-repeat-dynamic